# jQuery not running on divs imported with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code at end of `body`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = $(this).data('include');
      $(this).load(file);
    });

    var s = '.item .text';
    s.css('opacity', 0);
    $(s).hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 10}, 1000);
    });
});
```

The first part imports a bunch of chunks of HTML from external files, which contain a bunch of `.item` divs.

The second part is supposed to animated them fading in and out upon hover.

But the second part never works. Nothing happens upon hover.

Feels like something to do with execution order?

I tried this scripts both inside and outside of a `$(document).ready` block, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This line should be `$(s).css('opacity', 0);` I guess.

Comment: You should bind your `hover` event handler function, only after all the div's have been added to dom. Currently, when you are binding this hover function, there are no matching div's.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes, how do I do that?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please try if it works for you.

Comment: @Ze'ev did any of our answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(s).css('opacity', 0);` not `s.css('opacity', 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given below. I have only added the logic to wait till all div's have been loaded, assuming that your animating function is correct.

```
var numLoadedFiles = 0;
var numIncludesDivs = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    numIncludesDivs = includes.length; // store no. of divs to be loaded
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = $(this).data('include');
      $(this).load(file, function(){
         numLoadedFiles++; // update how many divs have been loaded
         if( numLoadedFiles === numIncludesDivs ){
            // all divs have been loaded now
            attachHoverHandler();
         }
      });
    });
});//document ready()


function attachHoverHandler(){
    var s = '.item .text';
    $(s).css('opacity', 0);
    $(s).hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 10}, 1000);
    });
}//attachHoverHandler()
```

Comment: This would be cleaner if you just pushed promises into an array, and then used `$.when` afterwards.

Comment: @meagar, thanks for your suggestions. Actually I haven't used promises in jquery yet. I will surely read further about this now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you @meagar. It really looks cleaner now. Can I add this code to my answer?

Comment: It's completely untested, I'm not even confident that it's syntactically valid. I would test it first, but feel free.

Comment: Ok @meagar, I will try to test it using `setTimeout` and add it to this answer, if it works fine. Thanks :)